# Complexity of simple division

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

What is the (a) worst case, (b) best case, and (c) average case complexity of the following function which does simple division

```
while n>=1 do
    n=n DIV 2
end {while}
```

How would you justify the complexity?

Comment: Are you just going to keep posting *all* your homework on SO ? Why not try some of these problems yourself first and then ask if you get stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

The function is `O(log n)`, since it will require exactly `floor(log2(n)) + 1` iterations.